# Repeatdely Changing App Background Colour : Android

Tags: android

I'm building an app that will blink the screen,
I need to constantly keep changing my android app background colour using

> setBckgroundColour

i got the basic background colour change working but when i implement the following code the app crashes

```
void testthread()
{
    new Thread( new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            Looper.prepare();
            //do work here
            while(true)
            {
            background_White();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            background_Black();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            background_White();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            background_Black();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }



        }
    }).start();

}
```

the functions background_White and background_Black

```
    public void background_White() {

    View flashScreen = findViewById(R.id.flashScreen);
    flashScreen.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

}

public void background_Black() {

    View flashScreen = findViewById(R.id.flashScreen);
    flashScreen.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Can you guys provide me with and insight on how to get my plan working?

Comment: can you provide error log?

Comment: well that's the problem nothing shows up in the error log it just force closes

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but Instead of thread try using **Handler**-Runnable as,

```
 handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1);  

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
public void run() {  
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() 
        { 
            //*change background here**/                       
        } 
    });
```

I think problem with your app is because of updation of your UI by another thread,Hence try using Handler-Runnable as above.

Comment: by error log you mean logcat messages right? there is not  asingle owrd that appears in logcat